# python - order list of dict based on dict values

Tags: python

Lets consider the following list of dicts:
`ins=[dict(rank=1, data="Pierre"),dict(rank=3, data="Paul"),dict(rank=2,data="Jacques")]`

How can I convert it to the following list:
`["Pierre", "Jacques", "Paul"]`

that is reordering the items with the `rank` key and only keeping the `data` key items?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it fairly easily with comprehensions and the `sorted()` function's `key` parameter:

```
ranked_data = [d['data'] for d in sorted(ins, key=lambda x: x['rank'])]
```

(You can also use `operators.itemgetter('rank')` instead of the lambda function, but the lambda is easier to use as an example here.)